# How to save and restore exact floating point values to a human readable file in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I need to be able to save and restore exact floating point values to a human readable (text) file from my C++ program.  I can use the %A format with sprinf to save the exact value, but I'm not able to find a way to restore it.  Using the %A format with sscanf is not working for me.

My sample program is below.  It successfully prints 0X1.921FB4D12D84AP+1 as the value of num1, but when I type that value back in, it sets num2 to 0.  I'm running in a Cygwin environment (DLL version 1.7.22) using GCC 4.7.3, G++ compile options include: -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    double num1 = 3.1415926;
    double num2;
    std::string input;
    int result;

    printf("%lA\n", num1);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "Got: " << input << std::endl;

    num2 = 0.0;
    result = sscanf(input.c_str(), "%lA", &num2);
    std::cout << "num2 is " << num2 << " and result is " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Comment: Have you tried "%a" (lowercase, no l)? (oops: keep the l)

Comment: Yes, neither %la or %lA work.  And yes, the l is required because num2 is a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you instead use the atof() function, or use boost::lexical_cast.  Both will accomplish what you want to do if you have a string with your number.

Comment: I don't think that recommending Boost to people who is clearly new to C++ programming is a good idea

Comment: Investigating, researching, and using new tools to solve problems - these are the ingredients to becoming better at C++.  He should look into it precisely because he's a new programmer.  I purposely left out the example code so he can research it and learn more.

Comment: I'm agree with that, but what I think is Boost is too complex to be used/learned by new C++ programmers. There are a lot of things to learn before to go to use Boost.

Comment: I'm not exactly a new programmer, I just haven't worked in C/C++ since the early '90s (with the old NIH class libraries).  I"m not opposed to using Boost, but I'd prefer to stick with the standard library if I can, and atof()'s cousin strtod() is what I need because it does some error checking that atof() doesn't do.  (I had completely overlooked the section on parsing of numbers in the GNU C Library documentation [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Numbers.htm) ).